# Paging not working at all

Tags: c#, gridview, user-controls, webforms, pagination

I created a user control with gridview in it which has another gridview in it, in live demo it works but not when I try it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="800px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="Horizontal"
     OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" EnableViewState="true">
```

then in code behind its

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    using (SqlDataSource SQLds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), Command()))
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = SQLds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But it says (1 click nothing happens, keep clicking then this error comes)

[image]

I went through thousands of posts but non worked for me

**Edit**

*There is no web.config and I already tried first 5 pages of google result using 10 types of keywords and errors, so If you are not sure then I going to cry !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed issue by putting gridview in a update panel.** since then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config you can add the following

```
<system.web>   
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
     <pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false"></pages>
</system.web>
```

This should disable your request validation.

**UPDATE**

You can set the same things on the page that is using the user control.

At the top of the page you will see a `<%@ Page` declaration. Put this inside it;

`EnableEventValidation="false" ValidateRequest="false"`

Comment: Note that this is the quick and dirty way to get rid of the error and show if paging is working.  You should still take the time to figure out what's tripping event validation and then reenable this setting.  You can also set this at the page level (probably better than app-wide) by using the EnableEventValidation and ValidateRequest properties in the @Page directive.

Comment: There isn't no web.config, it's a UserControl sir

Comment: @user13814 - you have a web.config for the site that's using the control don't you? Either that or set `EnableEventValidation="false" ValidateRequest="false"` on the page declaration that is using the user control.

Comment: Darren, I am not allowed to change web.config, thanks and sorry

Comment: See update. It basically says the same as my comment - which i'm not sure you fully read... you can do the same setting on a page level.

Comment: sorry I can't use Page directive either as it's a User Control and inheriting from masterpage with page directive I am not allowed to change

Comment: That's nor a property, that's a method.  The asker needs to know what control is causing the problem before registering values.  @user13814 Do you have any controls that are dynamically populated by Javascript?

Comment: nope, but there is a hide and show button using some JS, here;s the demo http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/

Comment: I fixed the issue by putting gridview in a update panel, thanks